# Can I refresh until an element is found in selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to know how it can refresh until the element is found, for some reason this code wont work, it just right through the loop.

```
while True:
    try:
        element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[text()="SIGN UP"]')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        driver.refresh()
    else:
        break
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="SIGN UP"]')
print("FOUND")
```

Comment: Why you are not using `wait` or `time.sleep()` in your code to wait until the presence of the element is detected.

Comment: Because it needs to keep on refreshing, I dont know how to let it wait while refreshing every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used selenium before but I'm going to make a safe bet that if the driver doesn't find anything matching that xpath, it will simply return `None`. In other words, your code is still valid because `element` is simply a `None`, thus not raising the error. What you can do instead is use a `while` loop to keep refreshing until it finds the element. Adding this function to a separate thread or process wouldn't be a bad idea either in case you have other things happening in the main loop.

```
def retry_until_id_found(element_id, max_retries=100):
    retries = 0
    while not driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_id)
        if retries <= max_retries:
            time.sleep(3)
            driver.refresh()
            retries+=1
        else:
            print(f"ELEMENT {element_id} NOT FOUND")
            return None
    print(f"FOUND {element_id}")
    return driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_id)

element = retry_until_id_found(r'//button[text()="SIGN UP"]')
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe below logic will help you

```
  `if(element.visible) //false
  {
    driver.refresh()
    n = 5 // you can give end limit
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
    if(element.visible) //true
     {
      driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="SIGN UP"]')
      print("FOUND")
      i=n; //break the loop
     }
    else
     {
      driver.refresh()
     }
   }
  }`
```